# DynamoDB read/write capacity explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to ask regarding the read/write capacity logic from DynamoDB. I looked at their documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html
and I also googled how they are related to the items in the db but I don't understand their definition.

So in my case,

I have a table like this
Hash key called `user_id` and sort key called `flag_key`

each item would be like this
`{user_id: 'user-1', flag_key: 'refresh_token', flag_value: 'some-random-refresh-token'}`
or
`{user_id: 'user-1', flag_key: 'roles', flag_value: ['role-a', 'role-b']}`

and other things similar to the above.

Now if I want to query 3 things e.g. `refresh_token`, `roles`, and `login_history`

I would query the dynamoDB 3 times.

So my question is,

does DynamoDB charge me 3 read capacity for that? Even though the combined items are less than 4KB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you make 3 different queries, you will use 3 RCU minimum.

However, since you are retrieving items for the same partition key, you may use a single query operation. As long as you make a single query and it returns all the data you need and that data is less than 4KB in total you will only use 1 RCU (read capacity unit).

Comment: does that mean it's better to represent the flags as columns instead and use ProjectionExpression? Because there would be lots of flags and querying them indeed would exceed 4KB. (there are array of logs there too)

Comment: Potentially, but keep in mind that the ProjectionExpression only saves you capacity when used to project into a GSI - otherwise it will only save network bandwidth.