# DynamoDB read capacity metric explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

from this question [DynamoDB read/write capacity explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417176/dynamodb-read-write-capacity-explanation) someone answered that each query of dynamoDB would take 3 read capacity.

However, after viewing the metrics I got this:

[image]

The latest point shows `0.3333333`

However, I used 2 GetItem in a single script. So is there any explanation for this? Shouldn't it be 2 read capacity?

Thanks! I'm new to DynamoDB and the read/write capacity can be confusing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at it averaged over 1 minute so that is a capacity of 60 reads per minute for 1 read unit.

If you only run one test of 2 reads it will smear out to a small number.  You need to run over a longer period to get a true measure of you read requirements.